# How to replace generated script for a custom one in jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I'm building a maven app using jenkins, the project is intended to run a .jar file. It currently produces a .tar that has a shell file named after the application name.

I would like to know whether is possible to replace the script that is being produced by a custom one. Currently what I could achieve, is to include the scripts in the tar file with this:

```xml
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>org-pom</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.myOrg.org</groupId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myOrg.division.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>myCurrentApplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>My Application</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <programs>
                        <program>                           
                            <mainClass>com.myOrg.division.group.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                            <name>myApplication</name>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                    <platforms>                     
                        <platform>unix</platform>
                    </platforms>
                    <binFileExtensions>
                        <unix>.sh</unix>
                    </binFileExtensions>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>appassembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>                 
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> 
                            <mainClass>com.myOrg.division.group.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assemble/bin.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The bin.xml looks like this:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
  <id>bin</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar</format>
  </formats>
  <baseDirectory>target/appassembler</baseDirectory>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>target/appassembler</directory>
      <outputDirectory>myApplication</outputDirectory>
      <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
      <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>src/main</directory>
      <outputDirectory>myApplication</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
                <include>conf/**</include>
                <include>scripts/**</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

But, this only includes them, instead of replacing them. Is it possible to have myCustomShell.sh instead of myApplicationShell.sh as the main script?

Note: I'm not able to change any configuration inside jenkins.

Thanks.

Comment: If you do not want to use the script created by `appassembler` plugin, then why configure and invoke it?  Why not just use package `myCustomShell.sh` in your assembly?

Comment: @Raghuram But that would not produce the main folder, right? I mean, it is doable, but I don't know whether it follows conventions.

Comment: What do you mean by `main folder`?  Also, the convention would be to use the output generated by `appassembler` - and not to generate it and then replace it.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of the appassembler plugin (current version is 1.2.2 (http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/).

Comment: @khmarbaise Hi. That is the version on the server, I am not allowed to change it :(

Comment: is there a way to replace the generated script with a custom one? I am building a shaded jar and I do not need the classpath and a lot of that other noise. Removing that after every build is a PITA.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I remember that I gave up, and I ended up creating a separate script to clean the mess because I couldn't find a way. Hope you post the answer if you find one.

Comment: @StrayChild01 - the latest version allows you to specify a different template but alas there is no way to  get the `finalname` of the assembly because it does not use the maven properties or filtering, it uses a proprietary properties list and filtering.